# Can you attach a debugger to a Java process after detaching?

Tags: java, debugging, jdwp

If you run a java process with arguments `-Xdebug -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=n,server=y,address=9000`, the process stops listening on the port once the debugger attaches to it. Then, once the debugger detaches, you can’t connect to it again. Is there any way to attach the debugger once it has been detached? Or is there a jdwp proxy server that is always attached to the process and allows the debugger to attach and detach at will?

Comment: I do this with JBoss and eclipse debugger all the time, and I can reconnect just fine. I don't know why wouldn't it be possible to reattach once detached. Do you have some other things to add that might have impact here?

Comment: Oh, you’re right. I didn’t realize that java tries to bind to the port again after the debugger detaches. And if there’s another process already at that port, it just logs an error `ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use`

Comment: I need to revisit the way I launch all my processes to make them debuggable (I currently search for an unused port above 9000 before assigning a port to jdwp, reusing if the port was assigned but that process is currently attached to debugger).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is yes, you should be able to just reattach. There should be no problems doing this. There might be a race condition if multiple applications try to bind to the same port during detach/attach, but I don't see any other possible issues.